# Ajax post not sending data out

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-post, send

```
var dataString = 'edulevel='+ edulevel
                        + '&course=' + course
                        + '&financerelated=' + financerelated     
                        + '&occupation=' + occupation
                        + '&joblevel=' + joblevel
                        + '&income=' + income
                        + '&bankname=' + bankname
                        + '&acctype=' + acctype
                        + '&accno=' + accno;


        //ajax
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "process/veriamateur.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: success(),
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                   alert("Error type" + textStatus + "occured, with value " + errorThrown);
                               }

            });
```

I have checked and made sure that dataString was sending out correct stuff, however, the ajax was just not sending out any data, no error whatsoever. Even when I changed the url to an invalid one it still went to my success function.

Comment: I think `success: success(),` should be `success: success,`.

Comment: I have a success() function below

Comment: Notice the lack of `()` in the second piece of code.

Comment: @musa do you mean my success function? it is function success()

Comment: No, I was refering to my first comment

Comment: I have several other files with success() but somehow they work except this one. Now that i removed it my code just mysteriously worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass data as an object instead of a string when you are sending via POST

Example:

```
data = {
  'edulevel': edulevel,
  'course': course
  (.....)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have made some changes and now this is working**  your callback function was success() and jQuery was trying to find the function, either you can write your function at same place or you can write a stand alone function and assign it to sucess:, if you are still getting problem try to change your url, if your current files location is `/files/file.php`
 then your veriamateur.php must be `/files/process/veriamateur.php`

```
var dataString = 'edulevel='+ edulevel
                        + '&course=' + course
                        + '&financerelated=' + financerelated     
                        + '&occupation=' + occupation
                        + '&joblevel=' + joblevel
                        + '&income=' + income
                        + '&bankname=' + bankname
                        + '&acctype=' + acctype
                        + '&accno=' + accno;


        //ajax
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "process/veriamateur.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){ alert('success');},
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                   alert("Error type" + textStatus + "occured, with value " + errorThrown);
                               }

            });
```